# Create a stored procedure in HSQLDB with Spring embedded databases API

Tags: database, spring, unit-testing, stored-procedures, hsqldb

I am currently trying to create a testing environment using an in-memory HSQLDB instance, created using Spring, thanks to its embedded databases support:

### Current set up

1. Creation of the "data source" for my unit tests:

   > ```
   > db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
   >          .addDefaultScripts()
   >          .addScript("stored_procedure.sql")
   >          .build();
   > ```
2. Content of "stored_procedure.sql":

   > ```
   > -- Mock of a more complex stored procedure in production environment
   > CREATE PROCEDURE GetFooById(IN fooId VARCHAR(12))
   >   READS SQL DATA DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
   >   BEGIN ATOMIC
   >       DECLARE resultSet CURSOR WITHOUT HOLD WITH RETURN FOR SELECT name, value FROM Foos WHERE id = fooId;
   >       OPEN resultSet; 
   >   END
   > ```

### Problem

I am able to initialize my schema and insert my testing data from the "default scripts", without any issue.

However, when creating the procedure, I am seeing errors like the one below, even after different versions of the above SQL, with/without delimiters, and with delimiters in various positions:

> ```
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected end of statement:  required: ;
>   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
>   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
>   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
>   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
>   at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.executeSqlScript(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:169)
> ```

### Resources and hints

I am using Spring 3.1.1 which provides HSQLDB 2.2.4, and based on the documentation, I would think I am doing the right thing.

However, discussions like:

- [This one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/forums/forum/73674/topic/4542791)
- Spring's JIRA ticket SPR-8817

make me think it may be an incompatibility between HSQLDB and Spring / an error caused by the way delimiters are processed.

But I am a beginner at both Spring and HSQLDB, hence my below questions.

### Questions

1. Has someone ever seen this before? And came up with a solution?
2. Is there an equivalent way of returning a result set using a select-from-where query in HSQLDB, given that the final stored procedure is called using *{call GetFooById ?}* ?
3. Could this effectively happen because of ResourceDatabasePopulator ? Is ResourceDatabasePopulator still causing troubles in Spring 3.1.1 ?
4. Any other pointer / hint?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

M.

---

EDIT:

### Conclusion & Solutions

**Problems**:

1. ResourceDatabasePopulator processes semicolons as query delimiters, which is not compliant with HSQLDB's syntax.
2. **{call GetFooById ?}** is a valid syntax for Sybase (my production database) but not for HSQLDB, which expects **{call GetFooById(?)}**. And of course the HSQLDB syntax isn't compatible with Sybase's one either. Besides, Spring's JdbcTemplate doesn't abstract away these differences.

**Solutions**:

1. Using Java stored procedures instead of SQL stored procedures can be a workaround as the query is written on the Java side and no semi-colon delimiters are involved. 
   Alternatively, I guess ResourceDatabasePopulator's logic could be changed and used to set up the embedded database, but I haven't tried this so far.
2. Spring's StoredProcedure class seems much more portable and can be used with both Sybase and HSQLDB, even if it is a bit more verbose than JdbcTemplate.

**Source code**: Available on [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/marccarre/spring-db-testing).

Comment: May I just ask why you do not use the same DB for PROD and DEV, or what I would suggest is generate different *.sql files for different DBs. And well a workarround might be as mentioned in the link to create your own Populator, which you could even submit to Spring sourceforge to have a setDelimeter() or wtv.

Comment: Spring has now implemented custom separators in the ResourceDatabasePopulator.  You should add that to your answer for one-stop shopping for others who have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. for stored procedures and object types you take care about JDBC driver of your database. For stored procedure, also for testing or other, create a package inside your database and call this for future test phase.
2. I used stored procedures and customization input/output object, using only Java SQL Stored procedure API, and customization where needed.

If you want explain your context and case, we can help you to find your best solution :-).